# Play 2.1.1 not loading custom Akka dispatcher

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, playframework-2.1

I'm using Play 2.1.1 and in `application.conf` I add the following custom dispatcher:

```
# Dispatcher for round-robin actors
play {
    akka {
        actor {
            rr-dispatcher = {
                type = BalancingDispatcher
                executor = fork-join-executor
                fork-join-executor {
                    parallelism-min = 2
                    parallelism-factor = 2
                    parallelism-max = 24
                }
                # messages per actor before jumping
                throughput = 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to use it on an actor:

```
private val default = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[MessageRouterActor].withRouter(FromConfig()).withDispatcher("rr-dispatcher"), "msgRouter")
```

But I get this message stating the dispatcher couldn't be found:

```
[info] play - Starting application default Akka system.
[WARN] [04/20/2013 22:05:12.069] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [Dispatchers] Dispatcher [rr-dispatcher] not configured, using default-dispatcher
```

As far as I've seen this seems to be the correct way to add it. Anyone knows what's the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to put the full config value path: withDispatcher("akka.actor.rr-dispatcher") (or perhaps even "play.akka.actor.rr-dispatcher")